# ASP.NET Singleton class values not consistent

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, singleton

I've a specific requirement to only allow 5 simultaneous access to a WebAPI (.NET 4.5 specific)  method (as part of a licensing plan). When the 5 simultaneous limit is reached, the webapi should reject any further attempts from *ANY* user.

I've created a Singleton class to count the number of times the method is accessed, and would decrement the counter after processing done,, and would do a check if the count > 5.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetOrderStatus/{id}")]
    public async Task<string> GetOrderStatus(int id)
    {
        GlobalState state = GlobalState.Instance;
        string result;

        if (state.OrderStatus > 5)
        {
            Log.Debug("INVALID - state.OrderStatus: " + state.OrderStatus.ToString() + ", ID: " + id.ToString());
            return await Task.FromResult("INVALID");
        }
        else
        {
            state.OrderStatus++;
            Log.Debug("state.OrderStatus: " + state.OrderStatus.ToString() + ", ID: " + id.ToString());
            result = DoGetOrder(id);
            state.OrderStatus--;
        }

        return await Task.FromResult(result);
    }

    private string DoGetOrder(int OrderTypeId)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        return "OK_" + OrderTypeId.ToString();
    }
```

My singleton class is below.

```
public sealed class GlobalState
{
    private static readonly Lazy<GlobalState> lazy = new Lazy<GlobalState>(() => new GlobalState());

    public int OrderStatus { get; set; }
    public int PlaceOrder { get; set; }

    public static GlobalState Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }
    private GlobalState()
    {

    }
}
```

Unit Test.

```
   using Flurl.Http;

   [TestMethod]
    public void GetOrderStatus_Returns_Valid()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int success = 0;
        int failed = 0;

        Parallel.For(0, 100, i =>
        {
            string url = "http://localhost:61803/api/getorderstatus/" + i.ToString();

            var responseString = url.GetStringAsync().Result;
            sb.AppendLine(responseString + ", ");

            if (responseString.Contains("INVALID"))
            {
                failed++;
            }
            else
            {
                success++;
            }
        });
    }
```

The results of the test is getting wrong. Log reproduced below.

```
2018-11-26 10:00:29.431 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: 2, ID: 0
2018-11-26 10:00:29.432 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: 3, ID: 25
2018-11-26 10:00:29.434 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: 4, ID: 50
2018-11-26 10:00:30.310 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: 5, ID: 75
2018-11-26 10:00:31.311 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 1
2018-11-26 10:00:32.313 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 26
2018-11-26 10:00:33.311 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 27
2018-11-26 10:00:33.312 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 51
2018-11-26 10:00:34.308 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 28
2018-11-26 10:00:34.308 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 52
2018-11-26 10:00:34.310 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 76
2018-11-26 10:00:35.309 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: 4, ID: 3
2018-11-26 10:00:35.309 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: 5, ID: 34
2018-11-26 10:00:35.309 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: 4, ID: 30
2018-11-26 10:00:36.309 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: 5, ID: 54
2018-11-26 10:00:36.309 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: 5, ID: 79
2018-11-26 10:00:36.309 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 77
2018-11-26 10:00:36.309 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 53
2018-11-26 10:00:36.311 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 2
2018-11-26 10:00:36.321 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 29
2018-11-26 10:00:37.309 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 5
2018-11-26 10:00:37.309 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 56
2018-11-26 10:00:37.311 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 7
2018-11-26 10:00:38.312 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 8
2018-11-26 10:00:39.310 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 57
2018-11-26 10:00:39.310 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 6
2018-11-26 10:00:39.310 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 10
2018-11-26 10:00:39.311 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 81
2018-11-26 10:00:39.312 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 9
2018-11-26 10:00:40.355 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: 4, ID: 14
2018-11-26 10:00:40.356 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: 5, ID: 4
2018-11-26 10:00:40.357 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 35
2018-11-26 10:00:40.357 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 36
2018-11-26 10:00:40.357 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 58
2018-11-26 10:00:40.359 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 18
2018-11-26 10:00:42.310 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: 3, ID: 78
2018-11-26 10:00:42.310 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: 3, ID: 84
2018-11-26 10:00:42.310 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: 2, ID: 59
2018-11-26 10:00:42.311 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: 4, ID: 31
2018-11-26 10:00:42.311 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: 4, ID: 55
2018-11-26 10:00:42.313 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: 5, ID: 37
2018-11-26 10:00:42.313 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 80
2018-11-26 10:00:43.313 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 11
2018-11-26 10:00:44.310 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 20
2018-11-26 10:00:44.310 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 12
2018-11-26 10:00:45.310 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 60
2018-11-26 10:00:45.310 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 13
2018-11-26 10:00:45.312 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 21
2018-11-26 10:00:45.312 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 19
2018-11-26 10:00:45.318 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 82
2018-11-26 10:00:45.320 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 39
2018-11-26 10:00:46.313 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: 3, ID: 46
2018-11-26 10:00:46.313 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: 4, ID: 64
2018-11-26 10:00:46.313 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: 3, ID: 69
2018-11-26 10:00:46.314 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: 5, ID: 22
2018-11-26 10:00:46.315 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 71
2018-11-26 10:00:46.315 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 61
2018-11-26 10:00:46.315 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 24
2018-11-26 10:00:46.315 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 44
2018-11-26 10:00:46.317 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 15
2018-11-26 10:00:46.321 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 85
2018-11-26 10:00:46.324 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 62
2018-11-26 10:00:46.324 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 87
2018-11-26 10:00:46.325 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 45
2018-11-26 10:00:46.327 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 16
2018-11-26 10:00:46.331 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 88
2018-11-26 10:00:46.331 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 65
2018-11-26 10:00:46.333 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 83
2018-11-26 10:00:46.336 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 40
2018-11-26 10:00:46.338 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 86
2018-11-26 10:00:46.338 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 23
2018-11-26 10:00:46.343 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 66
2018-11-26 10:00:46.345 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 63
2018-11-26 10:00:46.345 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 89
2018-11-26 10:00:46.345 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 17
2018-11-26 10:00:46.351 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 41
2018-11-26 10:00:46.352 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 67
2018-11-26 10:00:46.353 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 90
2018-11-26 10:00:46.355 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 42
2018-11-26 10:00:46.359 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 43
2018-11-26 10:00:46.359 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 68
2018-11-26 10:00:46.362 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 91
2018-11-26 10:00:46.365 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 92
2018-11-26 10:00:46.368 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 93
2018-11-26 10:00:46.371 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 94
2018-11-26 10:00:46.374 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 95
2018-11-26 10:00:46.377 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 96
2018-11-26 10:00:46.380 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 97
2018-11-26 10:00:46.383 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 98
2018-11-26 10:00:46.386 +00:00 [DBG] INVALID - state.OrderStatus: 6, ID: 99
2018-11-26 10:00:47.321 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: 1, ID: 38
2018-11-26 10:00:47.321 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: 1, ID: 32
2018-11-26 10:00:51.323 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: -1, ID: 47
2018-11-26 10:00:51.323 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: -2, ID: 72
2018-11-26 10:00:51.324 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: 0, ID: 70
2018-11-26 10:00:52.326 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: 0, ID: 33
2018-11-26 10:00:56.327 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: -1, ID: 73
2018-11-26 10:00:56.331 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: 0, ID: 48
2018-11-26 10:01:01.331 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: -1, ID: 74
2018-11-26 10:01:01.335 +00:00 [DBG] state.OrderStatus: -1, ID: 49
```

The state.OrderStatus value is getting to '6', for success and INVALID, and also it gets to negative in the log, and always not consistent.

Please advise what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Your code is not thread safe. Between the checking of OrderStatus and the increment of it, more than one thread can enter the if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a concurrency problem. The `if (state.OrderStatus > 5)` can be evaluated by multiple threads to false, after which they all increment using `state.OrderStatus++;` (which has a read-write issue on its own).

The solution is to use [`Interlocked.Increment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.increment) for such screnarios (note that `state.OrderStatus` should be a field in order for this code to compile, not a property):

```
int current = Interlocked.Increment(ref state.OrderStatus);

try
{
    if (current > 5)
    {
        Log.Debug("INVALID - state.OrderStatus: " + state.OrderStatus.ToString() + ", ID: " + id.ToString());
        return await Task.FromResult("INVALID");
    }
    else
    {
        Log.Debug("state.OrderStatus: " + state.OrderStatus.ToString() + ", ID: " + id.ToString());
        result = DoGetOrder(id);
    }
}
finally
{
    Interlocked.Decrement(ref state.OrderStatus);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Patrik ! I'll try it. Could you please explain/show what you meant by "state.OrderStatus should be a field in order for this code to compile, not a property" ? Appreciate very much for your time !

Comment: [What is the difference between a field and a property?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/295104/993547)